# Jquery nth-child removal

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-selectors, removechild

I have 3 images

```
<img>
<img>
<img>
```

When I remove an image

```
 $('img:nth-child(1)').remove();
```

It and then add another one.

```
$( '.hero .trim').append($img);
```

then try to remove the first one again

```
 $('img:nth-child(1)').remove();
```

It does not work. How do I get this to work so the new image is the first child?

Edit full code...

```
function completeIt () {
  $('.hero .trim img:nth-child(1)').remove();
};

if(this.talentClick == false) {

//$('.hero .trim img').append('<img>').attr('src', '/img/headers/'+deptname+'-header-mobile.jpg').attr('data-mobile', '/img/headers/'+deptname+'-header-mobile.jpg').attr('data-tablet', '/img/headers/'+deptname+'-header-tablet.jpg').attr('data-desktop', '/img/headers/'+deptname+'-header.jpg')




let img = '';
let width= $(document).width();



var $img = $('<img />').attr('src', '/img/headers/'+deptname+'-header.jpg').attr('data-mobile', '/img/headers/'+deptname+'-header-mobile.jpg').attr('data-tablet', '/img/headers/'+deptname+'-header-tablet.jpg').attr('data-desktop', '/img/headers/'+deptname+'-header.jpg')

$( '.hero .trim').append($img);


let firstimgheight = $('.hero .trim img:nth-child(1)').height();
let secondimgheight = $('.hero .trim img:nth-child(2)').height();


console.log($('.hero .trim img:nth-child(1)') );

 tl.to( $('.hero .trim img:nth-child(1)'), 0.2, {css:{marginTop: -firstimgheight+"px"}})
```

.to($('.trim'), 1, {css:{height: secondimgheight+'px'}});

Comment: Look into event delegation,your added element is not seen by jquery.

Comment: This is just for illustrative purposes- there is a container. It's more a question about how the Jquery treats nth-child after it is removed.

Comment: Is the problem that your code *does* remove the first image, but the first image is not the particular image you want it to be?

Comment: *"it does not work"* - what *does* it do?  How are you calling it?  Some comments here suggest event handlers, but you've not mentioned that your code is called from a click event or similar, so how/when are you calling the 2nd remove?  Where is `.hero .trim` in relation to the other 3 images.  Are the other 3 images in the same container?   Would be easier if you provided more context.

Comment: I'm not sure I see any problem using your code. You might have other issues keeping it from working. see working example: https://jsfiddle.net/r81fqe4m/

Comment: I think it is an event delegation problem as  Mihai said.

Comment: Sorry full code added.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `prepend` instead of `append` if you want the new image to be the first child(click the first button to remove the first child and prepend the new image and then click the second button to remove the newly added image):

```js
$(function() {
  var $img = '<img src="http://placehold.it/250x250/000/fff" />';
  $('button.one').click(function() {
    $('img:nth-child(1)').remove();
    $('.hero .trim').prepend($img);
  });
  $('button.two').click(function() {
    $('img:nth-child(1)').remove();
  });
});
```

```css
button {
display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="one">Button 1</button>
<button class="two">Button 2</button>
<div class="hero">
  <div class="trim">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250/fff/ccc" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250/ccc/aaa" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250/eee/ccc" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

See https://jsbin.com/fixelobeno/edit?html,output for an example using your tags.

```
  <div class="x">
    <img class="1">
    <img class="2">
    <img class="3">
  </div>

  <script>
  $('img:nth-child(1)').remove();
  $( '.x').append("<img class='new'>");
  $('img:nth-child(1)').remove();
  </script>
```

The first child is removed, then a new tag is appended to the div, and in the end the new first item is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume the parent div of these images has an id "main" for simplicity.
You need to use insertBefore instead of append. Example:

To remove the nth img:

```
$("#main img:nth-child(1)").remove();
```

To add the new img first:

```
$("<img src='' />").insertBefore("#main img:nth-child(1)");
```

`append` adds the item to the last position of the child tags. `insertBefore` adds it wherever you specify to add it.